# How to query more than 50000 records in apex and bind it in vf page in jqgrid and paging?

Tags: apex, soql, limits, largedatavolumes

How to query more than 50000 records (78000 records) in apex and bind it in vf page in jqgrid   and implement paging in it?

I tried querying through SOQL and assigning it to list.. Am unable to query more than 50000 records.

I tried offset but unfortunately offset doesnt accept more than 2000 as the number..

Tried database.getquerylocator and standardsetcontroller, but its returning only 10000 records and am able to bind it to jqgrid.

How to bind all the 78000 records to the page in jqgrid with paging (max 100 records per page)?

I have pasted the code below and in my assetcontroller am not able to give soql limit more than 10000. And I have even tried hitting the 100th Page (with each page having 100 records) and did con.getrecords() and again if I tried con.hasnext() it returns false, so it doesnt go beyond 10000 records at all..

@Jordan will it work if i give @remoteAction? if so what attributes (ex: datatype,url) do i need to change in my jqgrid ? and what else i need to do in my code?

// Visualforce page containing JQGrid :-

```
//Note AssetGridPage is a dummy page which will only return JSONresult given by the 
//controller and it is of contentType="application/x-JavaScript; charset=utf-8"

JQGridurl='https://c.cs11.visual.force.com/apex/AssetGridPage?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1&action=populateAssetSource';
var objectList = j$("#objectList").jqGrid(
                {
                        url: JQGridurl,                        
                        datatype:"json",
                        colNames: eval(ColNames),
                        colModel: eval(ColModel),
                        pager: '#objectListpager2',
                        toppager : true,                                                
                        rownumbers: true, 
                        gridview: true,
                        altRows: true,
                        enableSearch: false,
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortname: 'AssetID',
                        sortorder: 'desc',              
                        rowNum:100,
                        rowList:[10,25,50,100],
                        ignoreCase:true,
                        //pagination:true,
                        loadtext:'Loading...'                        
                    });
```

// Asset Controller Code

```
                  
// Getter Method: JSONResult
    public String getJSONResult()
    {
        return returnJson;
    }

    public PageReference PageLoad() 
    {
        Map<string,string> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        if(params != null)
        {
            PageNum = Integer.ValueOf((params.get('page') != null)?params.get('page'):'1');
            PageSize = Integer.ValueOf((params.get('rows') != null)?params.get('rows'):'100');
            CurrentPage = Integer.ValueOf((params.get('page') != null)?params.get('page'):'1');
        }
        else 
        {
            PageNum = 1;
            PageSize = 100;
            CurrentPage = 1;
        }
        populateAssetSource();
        return null;
    }

    public void populateAssetSource()
    {   
        Decimal RecCount = 0;
        String SOQL = 'SELECT AssetID__c, AssetDescription__c FROM Asset__c limit 10000';
        con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(SOQL)); 
        con.setPageSize((Integer)PageSize);
        setPageNumber();
        // sets the number of records in each page set      
        //system.debug('RecCount::'+RecCount);
        //system.debug('PageSize::'+PageSize);
        //system.debug('CurrentPage::'+CurrentPage);
        if(con != null)
        {
            AllSearchAssets = getAllAssets((List<Asset__c>)con.getRecords());
            RecCount = con.getResultSize();
            String JSONString = JSON.serialize(AllSearchAssets);
            returnJson =  '{"total":' +  '"' + ((PageSize==0 && RecCount ==0)?0:(RecCount/PageSize).round(system.roundingMode.CEILING)) +'",';
            returnJson += '"page":' + '"' + ((RecCount == 0)?0:CurrentPage) +'",';
            returnJson += '"records":'  +  '"' + RecCount +'",';
            returnJson += '"rows" : ' + JSONString + '}';
        }
        else
        {
            returnJson = '{"total":"0","page":"0","records":"0","rows" : []}';
        }
    }
```

The following code is in AssetGridPage.. empty page which is hit by the jqgrid

```
<apex:page controller="AssetController" action="{!PageLoad}"
    contentType="application/x-JavaScript; charset=utf-8" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
        {!JSONResult}
</apex:page>
```

@joshbirk so you are saying something like this?

```
List<asset__c> lstasset1 = Database.getquerylocator(Select id from asset__c where createddate > 'July-1-2012' and createddate < 'Aug-1-2012');

List<asset__c> lstasset2 = Database.getquerylocator(Select id from asset__c where createddate > 'Aug-1-2012' and createddate < 'Sep-1-2012');
lstasset1.addall(lstasset2);
```

And in the wrapper class of listasset1, add some pagenumber or some equivalent field. Foreach 100 increment the pagenumber variable.

Bind this lstasset1 to page based on some querystring filter and show only the 100. this is what you are saying right? if this is the case I cant go for a sorting of list. is there a possiblity to sort a list of wrapperclass type?

And one more limit we will be hitting is no. of query rows. we cant have more than 50000 records queried per transaction :(

So I guess even this solution wouldnt work.. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

I've done jqGrid before in Apex with `@RemoteActions` and it's definitely the way to go. I think with Ajax toolkit and SOAP, you'll have too much XML bloat compared to JSON for large sets of records.

As for loading all 78000 records, I would say you should stick to the limits of loading 2000 records at a time and than breaking those into further subsets of 100 records / page on the client side.

To pagination with large record sets I would recommend using the `standard set controller` for pagination. Just make sure to include an order clause to keep the records returning in the same order.

Than load the next 2000 records in each subsequent call. And reduce the number of records you return from the server to speed things up in between 'set loads' as you get to the end of each set and need more pages.

You can also `count` the number of records and return it in a complex object from the `@RemoteAction` to keep your pagination accurate:

```
public class returnType{
  List<sObject> objects {get; set;}
  Integer totalRecords {get; set;}
  Integer nextPage {get; set;}
  Integer lastPage {get; set;}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok using the SSC to maintain pagination (at least this is the way I would do it with jqGrid:

```
@RemoteAction
global static returnType pagination(Integer pageNumber){
   ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM sObject ORDER BY Id LIMIT 50000]);
   ssc.setPageNumber(pageNumber);
   ssc.Pagesize(2000);

   returnType retVal = new returnType();
   retVal.objects = ssc.getRecords();
   retVal.nextPage = pageNumber + 1;
   retVal.previousPage = pageNumber - 1;

   return retVal;
}
```

I don't have my original code in front of me, but generally, the SSC should be re-instantiated with each call. As for getting past 50k records, and to your total set, the query locator should continue to the end of the set reguardless of size taking the larger records towards the end of the set as you get to the end of `[0..n-1]` pages.

In practice I would use an ORDER BY clause to ensure your records are consistently returned in the same order to ensure that your getting all results.

Comment: How is he going to manage loading it chunks of 2000?  The Offset clause won't go higher than 2000 and he can't query the full amount via RemoteAction because he'll exceed the governor limit of 50,000 SOQL rows.  He could possibly handle it by creating an auto-number field on the object and using that as part of the where clause.

Comment: except that the auto number field is a text field, which messes with gt or lt comparisons right? unless your talking about an auto-number scheme that doesn't depend on the name field. haven't crossed that technique yet.

Comment: He should use the `standard set controller` for pagination.

Comment: Ah, I'll look into that.  I haven't had to implement that yet.

Comment: @E.J. - I hadn't yet noticed that offset only supports 2000 records. <<facepalm>> thanks for pointing that out. I wish SFDC stopped releasing brutally handicapped developer features like that.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your responses but not sure if you all looked at my last question here :- 
How to bind all the 78000 records to the page in jqgrid with paging (max 100 records per page)?

I am saying that am going to display only 100 records in a page but my dataset contains 78000 records.. When I do an SOQL i cant get more than 50000 in a controller method.

My situation here is :-
I have around 500,000 records in the custom object Assets.
Each set of customer has access to around 30 or 40000 assets and a few of them have access to about 75 to 78000 records. so i couldnt filter more :(

Comment: And Jordan thanks for your response, I have already mentioned in my post that i have used standardsetcontroller and database.gequerylocator am able to fetch 10000 records from that and bind it to jqgrid and on clicking next and previous buttons or setting page numbers in jqgrid, am able to pull that particular page and show in jqgrid. I am displaying only 100 records per page. since i have used standardset controller am able to achieve this.. but database.getquerylocator doesnt return more than 10000 records. If its more than 10000 (say 78000), it says "Too many query locator rows: 10001"

Comment: yes @jkraybill i have mentioned that in my question itself, offset doesnt support more than 2000 as the number

Comment: Jordan I just read your answer again, if I query 2000 records using database.getquerylocator with a proper order by clause, how do I determine the start of my next 2000 recordset and how I can query it (as I have to query a total of 78000 records)?

I mean if the first set returns 2000 records. How do i find the 2001 record using database.getquerylocator? Should I have an additional running number field and are you asking me to query based on that? if so how do i manage if the user clicks on a jqgrid column and try to sort it? and what if they filter the grid by giving some search keyword?

Comment: Sathya, an example of the SOQL pagination by CreatedDate might look something like:

SELECT Id From ObjectName__c WHERE CreatedDate < :currentPage Marker ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1000

Or

SELECT Id From ObjectName__c WHERE CreatedDate > :currentPage Marker ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1000

To go the opposite way.  Basically use the upper and lower range of CreatedDate in your current set, and then look 1000 more or less in the right direction.

However, since it is possible to have records the identical timestamps - this isn't perfect.  Hence some people use custom fields.

Comment: Wow, formatting sucks in comments.  Anyway - you could possibly up that limit, but I'm not sure I'd recommend it in an effort to keep your UI responsive.

Comment: Yeah @joshbirk Also my jqgrid has sorting capabilities for the all the fields that are displayed.. So I couldn't actually filter by any field. Moreover I have a search functionality implemented in that as well... So do you have any other ideas on how to handle my situation..?  :(

Comment: This is exactly the same code that I have written @jordan.baucke but it's not going beyond 10000. I mean even if I say limit 10001 at the end of my query inside the database.getquerylocator it's throwing too many query rows 10001 error. Except that am not using remote action... Instead in the jqgridurl property I am specifying the URL and jqgrid by default appends the page number to the URL query string when I click next. processing the URL through the same code That you have written & converting it to list<wrapper class> and doing Json.serialize and returning json formatted string for jqgrid

Comment: Are you using an `@RemoteAction` ? You shouldn't have to use `Json.serialize` in that case, APEX should just serialize it into JSON into it. Your right about jqGrid adds the page number to the URL parameters...your going to have to customize jqGrid

Comment: no @jordan.baucke am not using <Code>@RemoteAction</code> I have edited my question and added my code as the space here (comments) is insufficient for posting the code..

Comment: Oh I see. Well I believe the key to getting more rows out of the SSC is to reinstantiate it on each subsequent call.

Comment: I couldnt get you @jordan.baucke :(
Can you give me a quick sample code so that I can solve my problem?

Comment: @Sathya - ah, I see - so you're really wanting to be able to filter and sort against the full 78K data set?  If I really wanted to try that, I would freeze the UI and load the data in groups until there was no more.  I'd try CreatedDate as a marker first, which should work - but you have have to detect dupes.  If you bulk load in very large datasets, it might also get foiled.

Comment: @Sathya - you might also look at SlickGrid as an alternate to jqGrid.  It is much rougher and simpler - but handles large datasets well.

Comment: @Sathya (at the risk of spamming comments) the other thought is that handling data of this size in a performant way may be out of the scope of HTML.  You might look at more native/desktop based scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @joshbirk 
1. Createdate filter wouldnt work because I need to be able to sort by each and every field displayed in my grid.
2. I will look at SlickGrid, my problem is actually not with the grid, but with the controller for pulling more than 50000 records
3. I am using sites as this is for external customers. So It has to be within web and unfortunately I cant take it is desktop app :(

Any other suggestions to achieve a solution here?

Comment: Instead of the CreatedDate being a cutoff for pagination, I was just saying to use it to poll for about say ... ~10000 records at a time.  Then remove dupes, append to existing array, toss to grid plugin.  You'll have the 78K records at the end.  Whether the page would be performant, I just don't know.

Might also look at BlockUI to notify the user of load times, etc.

Comment: @joshbirk i have edited my question and explained a bit detail about your response and asked a question as well there. can you please respond?

Comment: Sathya, this missing ingredient is a loop between the client and server.  Client requests a batch, then sends up the last known CreatedDate.  Adds new batch.  Repeats until server responds with an empty array.  Again, JS Remoting would be more lightweight in that flow.

Comment: There are a horde of comments here but I wanted to point out that it may be better to order by Id which is new summer 13 so you dont lose records with the same created date between chunks.

Answer (score 10):

There's a lot to consider here:

1. You'll probably want to use JavaScript Remoting as the transport since you may need to be dealing with more than 1000 records at a time
2. If OFFSET can't work, you can use another field as a "marker".  It depends on how your data is structured, how often it gets bulk loaded, etc.  Some people have used a standard field like CreatedDate - others a custom autonumber.  Both have their caveats but can generally be bludgeoned into working.
3. Technically, be wary of how much data you are putting into the interface at any one time.  You can technically shove a lot into the page, but some browsers/scripts/devices will only be able to handle so much.

Comment: Thanks for your responses Josh :
1. I understand i am using more than 1000 records but at a time am displaying only 100 in the grid. Not sure how javascript remoting will help here?

2. Since I have 78000 records OFFSET doesnt work for me as it doesnt accept more than 2000. and If i have a createdate or some field, my records will be filtered and i wouldnt be able to show the data to users. I have mentioned my scenario in one of the comments below jordan's answer. can you please take a look?

3. I want to show only 100 records in the jqgrid per page
total data needs to bound in jqgrid is 78000

Answer (score 3):

You can use the AJAX Toolkit to query via Salesforce's Web Service API via javascript.  That will allow you to query any amount by pulling back chunks of up to 2000 records at a time using the query and queryMore calls.

See the AJAX Toolkit documentation here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

Although I doubt you really want to load that many records in one go, you can set Read-Only mode on your Visualforce page to relax the limit on how many rows can be queried:

```
<apex:page controller="myController" readOnly="true">
```

Read-Only mode is really intended for use where you'll summarize the results, not to return zillions of rows.

See "Working with Large Sets of Data" in the Visualforce Developer's Guide for more information about Read-Only mode.

Comment: There's still an issue of the request time itself.  If working with large sets of data, you'll more than likely encounter "Time limit exceeded" exceptions on the request.

Comment: Hi Alderete,

   I will just be displaying 100 records at the max in the page and not more than that but my data size is 78000 records. Only if i had to show everything in the same page at a time in the grid without any paging i would need this. moreover am doing other dml operations in the page, so i cant give readonly=true... Even though we give readonly=true we can bind only a list of 10000 records at the max to a VF page, that too if it needs to be shown at 1 shot. So this doesnt solve my problem :( Thanks for your input anyways..